# Stop a loop in a function from another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to stop a loop in a function from another function in JavaScript. Here is the code that I tried:

```
<a onmousedown="startLoop();" onmouseup="stopLoop();" >
   Start loop
</a>

<script>
var static loop = 1;

function startLoop() {
    while(loop ==1) {
    }
    alert("stop"); //This line is not executed
}

function stopLoop() {
    loop = 2;
}
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/A5h8k/4/

Comment: You can't; JavaScript is single-threaded so there's no way for anything else to execute while your loop is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `var static loop = 1;` is invalid, `var loop = 1;`, but you start an infinite loop, so you won't be able to stop it this way.

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead

```
var int = self.setInterval(function(){myLoop()},100);
function myLoop() {
    //do stuff
}

function stopLoop() {
    window.clearInterval(int);
}
```

Comment: Please can you give me an example ?

Comment: Your function won't be invoked if if you have quotes around it like that. Remove the quotes to pass the function. Also, is `self` a standard variable?

Comment: ...regarding your edit, you don't need the anonymous function. The way you had it was fine except for the quotes. `setInterval(myLoop, 100)`.